# PHP function for counting individual rows inside the (MySql) query loop returning null

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to include a php function into the query loop which simply outputs all rows from a table.

This function would return another query counting the rows of individual users and would be encoded together with the first query.

The function works, if I echo the userId variable I get it right, but for a reason the count query returns null.

I could use some help, thanks!

```
<?php

include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM UPLOADS";

//Creating resonse json array, with another array inside
$jsonResponse = array( "info" =>array() );

if($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

     $jsonRow = array(        
         'user'             =>      $row['USER'],
         'userId'           =>      $row['USERID'],
         'filename'         =>      $row['FILENAME'],
         'description'      =>      $row['DESCRIPTION'],
         'location'         =>      $row['LOCATION'],
         'address'          =>      $row['ADDRESS'],
         'likes'            =>      $row['LIKES'],
         'city'             =>      $row['CITY'],
         'lat'              =>      $row['LAT'],
         'lng'              =>      $row['LNG'],    
         'countPost'        =>      countUserPosts($row['USERID'])
        );          

        //adding the $jsonRow array to the end of the "users" array as key/value
        array_push($jsonResponse["info"], $jsonRow);
    }   

}

//encoding to json for the app
echo json_encode($jsonResponse);    

function countUserPosts($userId){

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT count(*) FROM UPLOADS WHERE USERID = '$userId' ");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    $num = $row[0];

    return $num;

}       

?>
```

Comment: Well first of all, I guess and ID is an integer and integers don't need to be between ' ', second, if you echo your query and paste it in your mysql, does that return null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to inject the mysqli object inside your function paramater:

```
function countUserPosts($userId, $mysqli){
                              //   ^ this one so it won't be out of scope.
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT count(*) FROM UPLOADS WHERE USERID = '$userId' ");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    $num = $row[0];

    return $num;

}
```

Comment: @EdmondTamas yeah, you need the connection on scope. im glad this helped